# Android app that displays notifications based on your location

Tags: android, notification, gps

Is there any android app that lets you to set a list of notifications templates and the location in which the notification should be triggered and then, when you are at that location, the app to trigger the notification you've previously set up?

Comment: You mean something like [location based reminders](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_locationalert)? So e.g. when you pass the supermarket, it tells you "remember to buy milk"?

Comment: @Izzy yes, more or less something like this

Comment: So why did you delete your question then? Found something suitable? Then maybe better [answer your own question](/help/self-answer), so others can profit from it, too!

Answer (score 0):

I found this app called NapAlarm: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yash.naplarmuno which pretty much does the iob.